# how to connect socket in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to connect socket using api with token and namespace. It showing error **Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting, Error during long poll request**

Here is my code for socket:

```
  import UIKit
  import SocketIO

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

static let authToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authToken")
static let bearerToken: String = "Bearer " + (authToken ?? "")
static let newBaseURL = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "baseURL")!
//static let v = newBaseURL + "/event-stream/?token=\(bearerToken)"

static let v = newBaseURL



static let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: v)!, config: [.log(true), .compress, .forcePolling(false), .forceNew(true), .reconnects(true), .reconnectAttempts(100), .forceWebsockets(true)])
static let socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/event-stream/")



class func connectSocket(){
    self.manager.config = SocketIOClientConfiguration(
        arrayLiteral: .connectParams(["token": SocketIOManager.bearerToken]), .secure(true)
    )
    socket.connect()
}

class func disconnectSocket(){
    socket.disconnect()
   }
 }
```

here is my error log:

```
    2020-01-27 15:05:36.607140+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[1517:468209] LOG SocketIOClient{/event- stream/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting, 2]
    2020-01-27 15:05:36.607465+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[1517:468209] LOG SocketIOClient{/event- 
   stream/}: Joining namespace /event-stream/
    2020-01-27 15:05:36.607579+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[1517:468209] LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
    2020-01-27 15:05:36.607653+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[1517:468209] LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
   2020-01-27 15:05:36.612981+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[1517:468391] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: api url
  2020-01-27 15:05:36.613238+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[1517:468391] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
  2020-01-27 15:05:36.635760+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[1517:468391] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET https://api url/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&token=Bearer%20eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhOGZsb3ciLCJleHAiOjE1ODAyNzcyNzAsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiZGVtbyJ9.SaoWMoYF-bp57fEXw0-EJAW9JDQZ8fyaYjCirL06M1Y
  2020-01-27 15:05:36.990748+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[1517:468395] ERROR SocketEnginePolling: Error during long poll request
 2020-01-27 15:05:36.990925+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[1517:468395] ERROR SocketEngine: Error
 2020-01-27 15:05:36.991075+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[1517:468209] ERROR SocketManager: Error
```

Any help much appreciated pls....

Comment: have you checked that any server-side issue or not? Use this [link](https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/) for server-side testing.

Comment: @HardikS its working there

Comment: you should remove extra slash from the end of the namespace. Like this `static let socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/event-stream")`

Comment: tried this too.still facing same issue @HardikS

Comment: are you sure that your server have open the port which will use in socket connection?

Comment: yes, it open..@MuhammadAhmedBaig

Comment: can you please share your `socket` connection URL?

Comment: @HardikS https://suryoday-staging.autonom8.com/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1&token=Bearer%20eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhOGZsb3ciLCJleHAiOjE1ODAyOTkyNTQsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiZGVtbyJ9.SE1BZURuK7RODk46EH9A4hXcsBJnTPy4w30XQb7PxsI

Comment: @HardikS excepted url : https://suryoday-staging.autonom8.com/engine-rest/?token=Bearer%20eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhOGZsb3ciLCJleHAiOjE1ODAyOTQwMTMsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiZGVtbyJ9.ILiILf7nvWsi311k9xqTdlT4kjrYrl56NXCjX9Qz1q0&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M_caFyD

Comment: @ParameswaranV check my answer and let me know it is working or not.

Comment: which URL you are using for socket connection? Because I have check with your given socket URL at [link](https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/) and it is not working there.

Comment: @HardikS  suryoday-staging.autonom8.com/engine-rest and passing token as query parameter

Comment: @HardikS any update..

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
class func connectSocket(){
    self.manager.config = SocketIOClientConfiguration(
        arrayLiteral: .connectParams(["token": SocketIOManager.bearerToken]), .secure(true)
    )

    //To connect socket
    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) { (data, ack) in
        print("socket connected",data,ack)
    }

    //To disconnect socket connection
    socket.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) { (data, ack) in
        print("socket disconnected")
    }
}
```

Comment: it disconnecting .. 2020-01-27 18:07:04.077272+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[1651:512673] LOG SocketIOClient{/event-stream}: Adding handler for event: connect
2020-01-27 18:07:04.077501+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[1651:512673] LOG SocketIOClient{/event-stream}: Adding handler for event: disconnect

Comment: Still facing same issue

Comment: have you tried to connect socket without namespace?